# irreducible subfactor inclusion and commutativity of induced projections

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors

Let $N\subset M$ be an irreducible subfactor inclusion, i.e., $N'\cap M =\mathbb C1$, acting on a Hilbert space $H$.
Let $\Omega\in H$.

Does it follow that the projections onto $[N\Omega]$ and $[M'\Omega]$ commute?

The irreducible subfactor inclusion is equivalent to $M'$ and $N$ being commuting factors on $H$ such that $N\vee M'=B(H)$, if that point of view helps.

Any help would be much appreciated!

If $M=N$ the answer is affirmative: the projection onto $[M'\Omega]$ commutes with $M'$, hence is an elment of $M$ and the projection onto $[M\Omega]$ commutes with $M$, hence is in $M'$. Since $M$ and $M'$ commute, so do the two projections.

Comment: I might misunderstand the question, but being cyclic and separating for both $N$ and $M$ means that both spaces $[N \Omega]$ and $[M' \Omega]$ equal $H$.

Comment: yeah, you're right I got confused with another problem while writing the question. I do not want to assume that. $\Omega$ is just some unit vector.

Comment: @StefaanVaes thanks for pointing that out! I edited the question.

Comment: @StefaanVaes, Pro Vaes, I have a question: If $M$ is a type III$_1$ factor,  does there exists an irreducible sbufactor $N$ of $M$?